# Express/NodeJS multiple mysql queries for the same route

Tags: node.js, express

In a blog made in express/nodejs I am trying to display in the single article page both the article (working fine) and a set of 2 recommended articles. Unfortunately as you can see in the commented bit of the code it doesn't work (can't render the same template twice)

What would be the best approach in this case?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {

var slug=req.url.replace(/^\//,'').replace(/\/$/,'');
var bg = getRandomInt(5);

if(slug==''){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE NOT slug = "about"', function (error, results, fields) {
res.render('index', { title: title, year: year, bg:bg, pages: results });
    });

}else{
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` where slug=?', [slug], function (error, results, fields)
             {
        if(results.length){ 

            res.render('page', { title: results[0].title, page:results[0] });
        }else{
            console.log(req);
            res.render('error',{url: 'http://'+req.headers.host+req.url});
        }
    });
    /* not working apparently you can't send the header of the template twice umhh
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 2',  function (error, random, fields)
             {
                res.render('page', { pages:random}); 

             });
    */

}
 });
```

Comment: You can't send a response twice. You will need to group the result of your queries and perform a single render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now

- Both queries will complete (and call their callback) at unrelated times
- res.render will be called multiple times, which does not work because it assumes all of the data is being sent in a single call. So it sends the HTTP headers, which cannot be sent twice.

Updated according to what it looks like you intended. Note this makes the order of the queries sequential, which may not be desirable. You'll want to use the `async` lib to help manage running them both at the same time and still consolidate the results:

```
router.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  const slug = req.url.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
  const bg = getRandomInt(5);

  if (slug == '') {
    return connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE NOT slug = "about"', (error, results, fields) => {
      res.render('index', { title: title, year: year, bg: bg, pages: results });
    });
  } else {
    return connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` where slug=?', [slug], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (results.length) {
        return connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 2', (error, random, fields) => {
          if (error) {
            // handle error
          }
          // consolidate renders into a single call
          // adjust the template file accordingly
          return res.render('page', { title: results[0].title, page: results[0], pages: random });
        });
      } else {
        console.log(req);
        return res.render('error', { url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.url });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Alternatively, consider using `bluebird` & `async`/`await`, this is just another style - to give you options that are new based on node 8+. In this one the queries are kicked off at the same time again.

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

router.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const slug = req.url.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    const bg = getRandomInt(5);
    if (slug == '') {
      const results = await bluebird.fromCallback(cb => connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE NOT slug = "about"', cb));
      return res.render('index', { title: title, year: year, bg: bg, pages: results });
    } else {
      const [results, random] = await Promise.all([
        bluebird.fromCallback(cb => connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` where slug=?', [slug], cb)),
        bluebird.fromCallback(cb => connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 2', cb))
      ]);
      if (results && results.length) {
        return res.render('page', { title: results[0].title, page: results[0], pages: random });
      } else {
        return res.render('error', { url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.url });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.render('error', { url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.url });
  }
});
```

Comment: this was super helpful. I didn't want to move all to async so having it sequential helped a lot! thanks.

Comment: @devnull glad to help - also raw query builders like that can be a bit painful. A lot of people use knex.js which internally handles building the SQL and binding the params.

Comment: I hear you and thanks for the suggestion... but old school here - there is nothing like real queries :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't render a page twice, otherwise you'll get [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

What you need to do, is fetch the current article and the recommended pages, and render the page once you have the results from both queries.

In order to achieve that I used: `Promise.all`, and then performed a single `res.render`

```
router.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {

    const slug = req.url.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    const bg = getRandomInt(5);

    if (slug == '') {
        const results = await query('SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE NOT slug = "about"');

        return res.render('index', {
            title: title,
            year: year,
            bg: bg,
            pages: results
        });

    }

    // Get current article and recommended pages
    // Promise.all returns an array where each entry has
    // the resolved value of the promise passed at that index
    const [article, recommended] = await Promise.all([
        query('SELECT * FROM `pages` where slug=?', [slug]),
        query('SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 2')
    ]);


    if (article.length) {

        // Render the article & recommended pages at once.
        res.render('page', {
            title: article[0].title,
            page: article[0],
            pages: recommended 
        });

    } else {
        console.log(req);
        res.render('error', {
            url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.url
        });
    }

});

// Query helper
// You can use promisify...
function query(statement, placeholders = []) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        connection.query(query, placeholders, (error, results) => {

            if(err)
                return reject(err);

            resolve(results);

        });
    });

}
```